# How to create new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I want to create new project in Android Studio.

But There is error message.

> There must not already be a project at this location

But There is empty folder at `'this location'`

Comment: You can see Video tutorial here

Android Hello World Example
[Android Tutorial For Beginners](https://youtu.be/-Cfl6BdLT5K)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to delete the empty folder.

What the error message should say is "There must not already be a *folder* at this location". The location you specify for the new project must not already exist, because the new project wizard wants to create the folder itself. This makes the whole idea of selecting a folder using the "..." button pointless, you can't select an already-existing folder for the project. It must be a non-existing folder in the "Project location".

I've just spent quite a long and frustrating time figuring this out.

Comment: In Android studio, when you want to create new project is workspace creating in eclipse. If you want to create project in existing workspace create "New module"
Eclipse workspace = Android studio project,
Eclipse project = Android studio module

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Disregard that, it made a project in the default dir, not the place I specified :(

I had the same problem.
The only way I could do it, is to delete projects at the default location (so when I go into Create new Project dialog it won't show me this crap right away). Then enter all the settings for my project and at the very end just paste the path to new project location right into the path field (not select it with their folder picker) and then hit Next.

It's very important to paste path and hit next at very end, so studio won't have time to validate entered path (it will, if you'll try to change some other fields)

Comment: Thank you very much.
But there is another problem occured.

'Failed to import new Gradle project' 

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Connection timed out: connect

Comment: By pasting the path in and clicking next quickly I was able to bypass this as well. Definitely annoying.

Comment: Why are you guys moving to Android Studio arent you ashamed of betraying eclipse your long standing friend?? Shame on you all!!!