# Cannot create new project - There must not already be a project at this location

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I am trying to start using the just released [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), I have already established the location for the Android SDK, and the Studio opens correctly.

Now, I want to create a new application project, but I cannot figure out what to select as project location.

Steps followed:

- Launch Android Studio
- Select New Project
- Enter Application Name, Module Name, Package Name.
- Click on the '...' button to select a project location
- Select the appropriate folder I created for the project, which **is empty**. See [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/archff7ehwcsp6f/project_path.png) here of the dialog at this point.
- Clicked Ok on the dialog, and now I am prompted with a **second** dialog, that is now labeled *'Select Path'*, where previous dialog was labeled 'Please choose a Project Location'. No matter what folder I select, the option for 'Ok' is grayed out and cannot be selected. [Image here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc1t379w36ck85o/project_path_not_working.png).

I read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580575/how-to-create-new-project-in-android-studio), and I am making sure, as you can tell by the steps I followed, that I am entering the path at the very end, and it still won't work for me.

I really think there must be a silly thing I am missing here, not sure what it may be though.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have permission for those folders right?

Comment: Yes Sir, those folders are on my Desktop folder, and I am the only user of the PC.

Comment: Check whether your working project folder path has any quotation marks or any stupid characters. Android Studio doesn't seem to like those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, apparently what caused the main problem is that the first time I launched Android Studio I didn't create a new project, I imported one, and that seemed to screw the whole workflow of it.

As per someone's answer, who was apparently removed, here are the steps.

1. Go to `C:\Users\Username\` and erase the folder named: `.AndroidStudioPreview`.
2. Launch Android Studio again, it will ask if you want to import any settings, select the option that doesn't import anything.
3. **Optionally** Configure,  Project Defaults, Project Structure, Platform Settings, and make sure that both the JDK and Android SDK are configured, for instance, I had to point Android Studio to a folder where the SDK had already been downloaded.
4. Create new project, and leave the default workspace that will now show, it should be `C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects`

That's it, just go through the setup wizard, and you're done.

Comment: It works but did you figure out how to create a separate workspace? Rather have any other folder then the default one to have projects.

Comment: In Android studio, when you want to create new project is workspace creating in eclipse. If you want to create project in existing workspace create "New module"
        Eclipse workspace = Android studio project
        Eclipse project = Android studio module
When you create new workspace select File->Create new Project , and at the and of path  (etc. C:/Documents) add /"name of workspace"

Answer (score 5):

This is a really simple issue. Android Studio likes to create the folder for the project on its own. That means you can't just select a pre-made folder. For example if you select `C:/Android Projects` with Android Projects being a folder, you must append a folder name to the location for Android Studio to create, for example `C:/Android Projects/NEW PROJECT`

No work-arounds needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround.Here's what I did :

1. Click on check out from version control.
2. Select git(I have a bitbucket account,but might work with github).
3. Put in repo-url
4. Select the parent directory(this directory will also become the parent directory of your android projects)
5. Then click clone
6. Select YES when asked if you want to create Android studio project from existing sources.
7. Select Create Project from existing sources
8. Don't change anything,select Next and then Finish.
9. Now it will create a new project at your selected location
10. Close android studio,go back to your parent directory and delete the project folder.
11. And now start your new project wizard,you should be able to see your parent directory listed in project location.Start typing details about your project and the directory will be updated accordingly.

Comment: That's not really the point, creating a new project through the Studi from scratch shouldn't be this hard. For this I can also create a new project in Eclipse, and then export via Graddle, and then import it into Android Studio.

Comment: Yes I agree it shouldn't be that hard :)

Comment: This solved the issue for me. It performs a reset of the root projects directory for "Android Studio" which seemed to be causing the issued. Now I am able to create new projects from the Android Studio Wizard

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this morning when trying to create a new project and found a simple way to get around it.

Choosing the path to the project folder was impossible as I kept getting the same error message 'There must not already be a project at this location'. What I then did was type out the path manually, but not all at once. To begin with I thought I'd just try to set a folder at the root of my drive eg. C:\AndroidStudioProjects. It seemed to be ok with this, which led me to try to add the rest of the path manually as well. So the final path would be something like C:\Development\Android\AndroidStudioProjects

This worked, no errors showed up and it let me go through the rest of the set up.

Hope this works for others out there who are facing the same issue.